# Testar método de entrada da classe principal com mocagem do Systemin na classe de teste

Tags: testes-de-unidade, junit

Como testo o `System.out.println()` dum método? O método que quero testar exibe a frase:

> Informe o nome >

Como testo se esta frase foi mudada ou não foi mudada na classe de `Test`?

**classe principal:**

```
public class Cliente extends PessoaFisica {  

protected static Cliente pegarDados() {  
        String nome, estado, cidade;  
        int cpf, telefone, numeroConvenio;  

        System.out.println("Informe o nome");  
        nome = Clinica.entrada.nextLine();  

        System.out.println("Informe CPF");  
        cpf = Clinica.readInt();  

        System.out.println("Informe telefone");  
        telefone = Clinica.readInt();  

        System.out.println("Informe o estado");  
        estado = Clinica.entrada.nextLine();  

        System.out.println("Informe a cidade");  
        cidade = Clinica.entrada.nextLine();  

        System.out.println("Informe o número do do convênio");  
        numeroConvenio = Clinica.readInt();  

        Cliente cliente = new Cliente(nome, cpf, telefone, estado, cidade, numeroConvenio);  

        return cliente;  
    }
```

**classe de test**:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;  
import org.junit.Assert;  
import org.junit.Test;

public class ClienteTest {  

public void pegarDadosTest() {  
        String nome = "André Nascimento";  
        ByteArrayInputStream entradaTest = new ByteArrayInputStream(  
                nome.getBytes());  

        System.setIn(entradaTest);  

        String esperado = "Informe nome" + System.getProperty("line.separator");  

        Cliente.pegarDados();  

        String atual = entradaTest.toString();  

        Assert.assertEquals("metodo pegarDados falhou.", esperado, atual);  
    }
```

Comment: Você está querendo testar se o `Scanner` funciona? Você deveria estar testando o seu código, não o código do SDK do Java.

Comment: @Pablo Almeida na verdade, eu só quero testar a mensagem que o método escreve e não a leitura.

Comment: Me parece que seu método faz duas coisas? Um código mais modular é um código mais testável. Se você separar as responsabilidades desses métodos, vai ver que você não tem o que testar aí. A função recebe uma string e imprime. Se tiver algo errado nisso, é problema no Java.

Answer (score 0):

Parar testar o `System.out.println`, você pode criar um `OutputStream` e passá-lo para o método `System.setOut`. Dessa forma, quando o `System.out.println` for chamado, a saída será escrita no seu `OutpuStream` e você poderá acessar essa saída posteriormente. Contudo, no seu caso, você não tem como testar cada chamada individualmente. O seu método é um só, portanto, você teria que testar a saída inteira.

Exemplo:

```
public class PegarDadosTest {

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    //Aqui você está adicionando o seu outputStream como saída padrão. Quando o comando
    //System.out.println for chamado, o conteúdo será escrito na variável outContent.
    //Dessa forma, você poderá verificar o que está sendo escrito no out.
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
        // Você também pode passar o seu InputStream para o System. Dessa forma, você não precisa inputar dados
        // no console.
        InputStream inputStram = new ByteArrayInputStream(getInput().getBytes());
        System.setIn(inputStram);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws IOException {
        outContent.close();
        System.setOut(null);
        System.setIn(null);
    }

    //Testa se as mensagens impressas pelo método estão corretas
    @Test
    public void pegarDadosTest() {
        Cliente.pegarDados();
        Assert.assertEquals(getExpected(), outContent.toString());
    }

    private String getInput() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("João\n");
        builder.append("123\n");
        builder.append("456\n");
        builder.append("Estado\n");
        builder.append("Cidade\n");
        builder.append("1");
        return builder.toString();
    }

    private String getExpected() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Informe o nome\n");
        builder.append("Informe CPF\n");
        builder.append("Informe telefone\n");
        builder.append("Informe o estado\n");
        builder.append("Informe a cidade\n");
        builder.append("Informe o número do do convênio\n");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Porém, conforme já mencionado nos comentários da sua pergunta. Esse seu teste não é necessário. O que você tem que testar é o retorno do seu método e não o que ele está fazendo no meio. Nesse caso, o que você poderia testar é se o objeto Cliente retornado é o esperado. Verificar o `System.out.println` é útil quando o método é void e ele imprime alguma mensagem na console quando executado com sucesso ou quando dá algum erro.

Um teste mais interessante seria esse:

```
//Testa se o cliente foi montado corretamente
    @Test
    public void pegarDadosClientTest() {
        Cliente atual = Cliente.pegarDados();
        Cliente expected = getClienteExpected();
        Assert.assertEquals(expected.getNome(), atual.getNome());
        Assert.assertEquals(expected.getCpf(), atual.getCpf());
        Assert.assertEquals(expected.getTelefone(), atual.getTelefone());
        Assert.assertEquals(expected.getEstado(), atual.getEstado());
        Assert.assertEquals(expected.getCidade(), atual.getCidade());
        Assert.assertEquals(expected.getNumeroConvenio(), atual.getNumeroConvenio());
    }

    private Cliente getClienteExpected() {
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente("João", 123, 456, "Estado", "Cidade", 1);
        return cliente;
    }
```

Esse trecho de código você pode utilizar dentro da classe do código anterior.